# Is Swift good for iOS Game development?

Tags: ios, swift

I am new with Swift concept and its usage for apps/game development.

Does swift or xcode 6 beta include the tool for Game development ?

Comment: Well, someone implemented Flappy Bird and someone else implemented 2048. That's probably all you need to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode 6 and iOS 8 includes SceneKit (3D) and SpriteKit (2D) for game development.

Documentation is here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/SceneKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same APIs that were available in Objective-C in Swift. So yes, it is "good" for game development.